# NewForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx, DispForm.aspx

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part-pages

At this url, `servername/sites/lists/mylist/` we have three type of pages `NewForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx and DispForm.aspx` 
where are these 3 pages stored? Are these pages publishing pages?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the pages if you open the SharePoint Designer and go to the list. Once inside. Look for the section forms. See the highlighted section in the image. 
Another way would be to go to the "All Files" section in the left pane. From there click on the folder named Lists and look for `mylist`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are not the Publishing Pages. These come with the lists by default and you can customize it however you want.

Each list type generally has a set of display, edit, and new form ASPX pages (DispForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx, and NewForm.aspx) that are provisioned when lists are provisioned. These ASPX pages are provisioned into the "content space." In other words, they are not located in %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS, and they do not operate through the /_layouts virtual directory.

For document libraries, these pages are instead provisioned within a hidden subfolder of the list called forms. For other SharePoint lists, the pages are provisioned under the list root folder. Each of these ASPX pages contains a Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart object that serves to render the form.

Answer (score 0):

This pages are bases on standard pages.

You can customize this pages using SharePoint Designer. But you lost the standard wich is not always a good decision.

A tip to add customizacion without change the standard is edit the page. This option is hidden but you can edit the page adding the following parameter to the URL:

?toolpaneview=2

Hope it will be helpful.